# Trouble with jumping and remembering jump time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my character be able to jump whenever he is grounded OR if he's airborne to only be able to jump when he has extra jumps and x amount of time has passed.
Currenty I have this:´

```
void Jump()
{
    jumpTime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    if ((jumpRemember > 0) && ((groundRemember > 0) || ((jumps>0) && (jumpTime <= 0))))
    {
        jumpRemember = 0;
        groundRemember = 0;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        jumps--;
        jumpTime = timeSinceLastJump;
    }
}
```

(the jump remember and ground remember are checks to see if i pressed the jump button or was grounded in the last 0.1 seconds)

but when he is grounded and collides with a roof and get sent back to ground he cant jump after the time has passed anyways, even though I used the ''OR'' operator.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your variables `jumpRemember` and `groundRemember` but I'm guessing your issue is that you call `Jump()` when a players clicks the Jump button and it's only in this code that you do `jumpTime -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;`. So basically the `jumpTime` will only decrease when the player clicks jump, which is probably not what you want. Instead of relying on decreasing value every frame, I'd use time-checks instead.

Comment: `groundRemember` should be a Boolean... but show us where that changes

Comment: @rfmodulator i have 
`groundRemember -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            groundRemember = groundRememberTime;
        }`
so its technically a boolean

Comment: @FredrikSchön i will look into time checks, thanks

Comment: @ToBeFrank I'm with you now... `isGrounded` makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misplaced parenthesis. You want both of the first two true or both of the second two right?

```
if ((jumpRemember > 0) && ((groundRemember > 0) || ((jumps>0) && (jumpTime <= 0))))
```

should it be?

```
if ((jumpRemember > 0 && groundRemember > 0) || (jumps>0 && jumpTime <= 0))
```

That second parenthesis in front of groundRemember is causing it to be grouped with the two to the right of the or statement. You are requiring remember all the time and then either ground remember > 0 OR the other two to both be true. It doesn't sound like that is what you are intending. Is it?

Comment: That was it! got too much of a mess and couldn't see it on my own, thx a lot!

Comment: Authors don't proofread their own English for the same reason it is hard for us to proofread our own code. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using Debug.Log(variable) to check the states of your variables.

"when he is grounded and collides with a roof and get sent back to ground" - What variables does this change?

Are any of these variables being changed unexpectedly when the character collides with the roof?

I would leave this in a comment but you need reputation to unlock that feature of this site.

Comment: Heh, I was very close to downvoting until I saw that last paragraph. Have an upvote, so you can rid yourself of those silly restraints. There is a point to them though, of course, but preventing people from adding value is certainly not the point!

Comment: same for me LOL :)

Comment: oops, actually meant when jumping from groundedbut the fix was what @Rodger proposed, thx anyways

Answer (score 2):

An example how you could approach your issue.

```
const int MAX_JUMPS = 2;
const FLOAT JUMP_TIMER = 1;
const float JUMP_FORCE = 100;

int jumps = 2;
float nextJump = 0;
bool grounded = true;


void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
       TryJump();
}

void TryJump() 
{
    if (grounded || (jumps > 0 && nextJump < Time.time)) 
    {
        Jump();
    }

}

void Jump() 
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JUMP_FORCE);
    jumps--;
    nextJump = Time.time + JUMP_TIMER;
}

void Grounded() 
{
    grounded = true;
    jumps = MAX_JUMPS;
}

void Airborne()
{
    grounded = false;
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) 
{
    if (col.tag == "Floor")
        Grounded();

}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision col) 
{
    if (col.tag == "Floor")
        Airborne();

}
```